# how to merge data from 2 rows of different tables based on a common field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables `order_management` and `order_management2` which are almost same... `order_id` in `order_management` is *auto-incremented* where as `order_id` in `order_management2` not. I want to merge data of each field from both tables based on the `order_id`.

suppose,

**order_management table**

```
order_id      customer_name     fone no.      
--------      -------------    ---------
1              A                89000
2              B                78989
3              C                56464
```

**order_management2 table**

```
  order_id        customer_name      fone no.
 ----------      ---------------    ----------
   2                D                 89076
   3                E                 67598
   4                F                 67545
```

if `order_id` of both tables is `2` then, it should be displayed like:

```
 order_id        customer_name      fone no.
 ----------      ---------------    ----------
   2                B,D               78989,89076
   3                C,E               56464,67598
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT order_id,GROUP_CONCAT(customer_name SEPARATOR ',')as customer_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(`fone no.` SEPARATOR ',')as `fone no.` 
FROM order_management o JOIN order_management2 o2 
ON o.order_id=o2.order_id GROUP BY o.order_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
SELECT
  t1.order_id,
  CONCAT(t1.customer_name, ',', t2.customer_name) AS customer_name,
  CONCAT(t1.phone, ',', t2.phone) AS phone_no
FROM order_management t1
JOIN order_management2 t2 ON t1.order_id = t2.order_id
GROUP BY t1.order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```sql
SELECT order_id, GROUP_CONCAT(customer_name SEPARATOR ', ') cname, GROUP_CONCAT(fone_no SEPARATOR ', ') fno
FROM order_management o1
    LEFT JOIN order_management2 o2 ON o1.order_id = o2.order_id
GROUP BY o1.order_id
```

By this You should receive the requested results.